# Need help to create an XSL file that will transform the input XML file input.xml to the format of output.xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to:

1. Transform the `input.xml` (file below) to the format of `output.xml`
2. Create another XLS that will display per each amount: `KG`, `PAL` and `M3` the 
   total values;
3. Replace the tag `<quantity>` with the tag `<amount>` in the same XSL from 
   point 2;
4. create another XSL which is just adding an extra tag `<hour>` for each 
   `<order>` and display inside this tag the hour of loading (`hh:MM`)

But at first I need to convert this file (`input.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<output>
<orders>
    <order>
        <id>1</id>
        <number>10002</number>
        <type>Loading</type>
        <date>2013-01-01T02:30:00</date>
    </order>
    <order>
        <id>2</id>
        <number>10003</number>
        <type>Loading</type>
        <date>2013-01-01T010:30:00</date>
    </order>
    <order>
        <id>3</id>
        <number>10004</number>
        <type>Loaded</type>
        <date>2013-01-01T12:30:00</date>
    </order>
</orders>
<quantities>
    <quantity>
        <id_order>1</id_order>
        <unit>KG</unit>
        <value>1000</value>
    </quantity>
    <quantity>
        <id_order>1</id_order>
        <unit>PAL</unit>
        <value>3</value>
    </quantity>
    <quantity>
        <id_order>1</id_order>
        <unit>M3</unit>
        <value>1.5</value>
    </quantity>
    <quantity>
        <id_order>2</id_order>
        <unit>KG</unit>
        <value>2000</value>
    </quantity>
    <quantity>
        <id_order>2</id_order>
        <unit>PAL</unit>
        <value>4</value>
    </quantity>
    <quantity>
        <id_order>3</id_order>
        <unit>KG</unit>
        <value>5000</value> 
    </quantity>
</quantities>
</output>
```

To this file (`output.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<output>
<orders>
    <order>
        <id>1</id>
        <number>10002</number>
        <type>Loading</type>
        <KG>1000</KG>
        <PAL>3</PAL>
        <M3>1.5</M3>
    </order>
    <order>
        <id>2</id>
        <number>10003</number>
        <type>Loading</type>
        <KG>2000</KG>
        <PAL>4</PAL>
    </order>
    <order>
        <id>3</id>
        <number>10004</number>
        <type>Loaded</type>
        <KG>5000</KG>
    </order>
</orders>
</output>
```

**I tried this one but it is not complete, I don't know how to convert values (like: `PAL` in input file) to atributes (like `<PAL>...</PAL>` in output file). I have looked around and tried few things but it is not working. Can someone help me with this. Below is my XSLT. Thanks in advance.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl: template match = "/">
    <output>
            <xsl: for-each select = "orders/order[id = 1]">
            <order>
                    <xsl: value-of select = "id"/>
                    <xsl: value-of select = "number"/>
                    <xsl: value-of select = "type"/>
            </order>
            </xsl: for-each>
            <xsl: for-each select = "quantities/quantity">
            <order>
                    <xsl: value-of select = "id"/>
                    <xsl: value-of select = "number"/>
                    <xsl: value-of select = "type"/>
            </order>
            </xsl: for-each>
    </output>
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Please include your XSLT that is not working as expected.

Comment: What's the question? I only see statements.

Comment: Some ideas to get you started: http://www.xmlmaster.org/en/article/d01/c07/ and http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-introxslt/x-introxslt.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link the quantities to their respective orders by matching the order id. The best way to do this is by using a **key**:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="qty" match="quantity" use="id_order"/>  

<xsl:template match="/">
<output>
    <orders>
        <xsl:for-each select="output/orders/order"> 
            <order>
                <xsl:copy-of select="id|number|type"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('qty', id)">
                    <xsl:element name="{unit}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>  
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </order>    
        </xsl:for-each>
    </orders>
</output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that we are assuming that each order has no more than one quantity of each unit (i.e no summing is required).  Also it seems to me that the target structure is  less useful than what you're starting with.