# need help to create a file that will display per each amount the total value

Tags: xml, xslt

Create an XLS that will display per each amount: KG, PAL and M3 the total values. 
and Replace the tag  with the tag  in the same XSL.
I've tried everitying.
Tge only thing I was able to do is find the toatal amount of every value (8008.5) but not for each amount.

here the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<output>
    <orders>
        <order>
            <id>1</id>
            <number>10002</number>
            <type>Loading</type>
            <date>2013-01-01T02:30:00</date>
        </order>
        <order>
            <id>2</id>
            <number>10003</number>
            <type>Loading</type>
            <date>2013-01-01T010:30:00</date>
        </order>
        <order>
            <id>3</id>
            <number>10004</number>
            <type>Loaded</type>
            <date>2013-01-01T12:30:00</date>
        </order>
    </orders>
    <quantities>
        <quantity>
            <id_order>1</id_order>
            <unit>KG</unit>
            <value>1000</value>
        </quantity>
        <quantity>
            <id_order>1</id_order>
            <unit>PAL</unit>
            <value>3</value>
        </quantity>
        <quantity>
            <id_order>1</id_order>
            <unit>M3</unit>
            <value>1.5</value>
        </quantity>
        <quantity>
            <id_order>2</id_order>
            <unit>KG</unit>
            <value>2000</value>
        </quantity>
        <quantity>
            <id_order>2</id_order>
            <unit>PAL</unit>
            <value>4</value>
        </quantity>
        <quantity>
            <id_order>3</id_order>
            <unit>KG</unit>
            <value>5000</value> 
        </quantity>
    </quantities>
</output>
```

I Konw it seems tat the question has been answer arleady, but I've looked everywere in this forum, and didn't find anything. Probably I've looked in the wrong directions, so please adress me to the solution.

Thank you in advance

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516772/how-to-apply-xslt-transformations-to-xml-file-and-produce-another-xml/24517332#comment37974417_24516772

Comment: @michael.hor257k please note that this post has yes the same input, but the required assignment is different. i've already done the first part, that required to transform the input in output. This is something different. Can you help me?
Thank you in advance